# $\max(x,y,z)$: Spivak Chapter 1, Problem 13

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

After  proving $$\max(x,y) = \frac{x+y+|y-x|}{2}$$ Spivak asks to derive a formula for
$$\max(x,y,z) = \max(x,\max(y,z))$$ giving the hint as formulated above.

Here's my work.

Let $p = \max(y,z)$. Thus $$\max(y,z) = \frac{y+z+|z-y|}{2}$$ Thus $$ \max(x,max(y,z)) = \max(x,p) = \frac{x+p +|p-x|}{2}$$ and $$\max(x,y,z) = \frac{x + \frac{y + z + |z - y|}{2} + \left |\frac{y + z + |z-y|}{2} -x \right |} {2}.$$ I will omit the last step as this is not my question.
Just to show you Spivak's work, here it is. $$ \max(x,y,z) = \max(x,max(y,z)) = \frac{x + \frac{y + z + |y - z|}{2} + \left |\frac{y + z + |y - z|}{2} -x \right |} {2}$$ The only difference is the order of $y,z$ as an absolute value.
It may seem like a small issue, but I want to understand the difference. Thanks.

Comment: There is no difference, since $|y-z| = |z-y|$. You are accounting for the absolute value of the difference of $y$ and $z$. Maybe you should examine why is this term in $\max\{x,y\}$ (try with numbers!).

Comment: @thewatcher  First off, thank you. I thought this might be the case, but I don't like the fact that he formulates it in a certain order in his initial proof, but in a reverse order later.  I understand the fact that they are the same because of the application of absolute value, but I don't like the fact that it seems to be arbitrary.